# Source/Target compatibility list in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am in the process of updating my Android studio, Android build tools, gradle version and JDK version. Trying to switch to JDK 1.8 I am wondering why the list in the Android Studio dropdowns for "Target compatibility" and "Source compatibilty" (in the module settings) only contain the values 1.6 and 1.7. Does this mean I forgot to install/update anything or forgot to change some path?

I know I can enter 1.8  manually, but the question is whether the missing 1.8 value means my setup might be incorrect?

Comment: Is the JDK path set to 1.8?

Comment: I just found it was not, but after changing it the dropdown is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Source and target compatibility has nothing to do with installed JDK. Your source code will still be compiled to Java 6/7/8 byte code which is used by Android. (Someone in comments, please point out technical inaccuracies, thanks.)

Source and target compatibility affects language constructs you can use in source code. E.g.

- when targeting Java 6 you can't use the diamond operator,
- when targeting Java 7 you can't use lambdas, etc.

Android Studio 3.0 and accompanying build plugin for Gradle (currently in development) will support Java 8 syntax out-of-the-box. Until then you could use [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda). Or straight up switch to [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/).

And of course then you'll need at least JDK 8 to target Java 8.

Comment: You can use some Java 8 features with the jack compiler e.g. lambda expression.

Comment: @MuratK. Jack is officially dead. https://adtmag.com/articles/2017/03/15/android-nixes-jack.aspx

Comment: Yes, it's deprecated as of now. But you can still use it and the dev team promised a smooth transition to AS 3.0 with the jack toolchain.